# Moment library with assemble

Tags: assemble

I have another Assemble issue - I'm trying to get moment to format a date. But the helper doesn't seem to work.

I've tried both:

`sudo npm install helper-moment --save-dev`
& 
`sudo npm install handlebars-helper-moment --save-dev`

The module installs okay, I'm assuming the more recent one is `helper-moment` as it's in the documentation.

Then I've added the helper to the Gruntfile.js:

```
assemble: {
    options: {
        layout: 'page.hbs',
        layoutdir: './src/content/layouts',
        partials: ['./src/content/partials/**/*.hbs', './src/content/partials/**/*.md'],
        assets: 'assets',
        helpers: ['helper-moment', './src/compile/helpers/**/*.js'],
        data: ['package.json', './src/content/data/*.json'],
        marked: {
            breaks: false,
            gfm: true,
            langPrefix: 'language-',
            pedantic: false,
            sanitize: false,
            silent: false,
            smartLists: false,
            smartypants: false,
            tables: true
        }
    },
    project: {
        files: [{
            cwd: './src/content/pages',
            dest: './dist/www',
            expand: true,
            src: ['**/*.hbs']
        }]
    }
},
```

I ran Grunt and no complaints that it can't find the helper.

Then, from the template:

```
<div class="col s12 m12 l9">
  <div class="col m12 s12 l7">
    {{moment}}
```

I've tried in a partial and in a normal template. But it doesn't output anything, no errors anywhere, it just doesn't output.

Is there any way to debug the template build process? I'd love to be able to see some logging from the modules...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Assemble 0.6+** the [handlebars-helpers](https://github.com/assemble/handlebars-helpers) project is not added by default. That means that you have a limited built-in helpers to use. I just checked and that specific helper is added in the project: https://github.com/assemble/handlebars-helpers/blob/dba009ef72173dbc8c19b346ffa0c62de71d63f9/docs/helpers/dates/helper-moment.md So, if you import the project and register the new helpers, that should make it work. I could make it work using Assemble 0.9 and the dev branch of handlebars helpers.

Comment: I'm running into a similar problem, so I'm very glad to hear that you got something to work.  Can you provide details (an example) on how to register additional helpers with assemble?  

The docs are very hit and miss right now.  I know how to register a custom helper as a one off, but I would like to know how to register a suite of helpers.

`app.helper('markdown', require('helper-markdown'));`

Comment: Hi @JohnGully I was able to register handlebars-helpers project in Assemble 0.9.2 using the following syntax:

`const helpers  = require('handlebars-helpers')();`

That should make all the custom helpers from the old Grunt version be available in the new version. If you want to register others, you could always use the syntax you used in the comment above inside a forEach method.